# How to trigger button from input type=text in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want when I type in my search box to trigger a button in javascript.

This is my input box:

```
<input
  id="search_filter1"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Search team..."
  name="search"
  onkeyup="search_filter()"
>
```

The javascript for the button I want to trigger when I type in the input box:

```
function view_all() {
    var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
    var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
    var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");
  
    if (dots.style.display === "none") {
      dots.style.display = "inline";
      btnText.innerHTML = "View all";
      moreText.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      dots.style.display = "none";
      btnText.innerHTML = "View less";
      moreText.style.display = "list-item";
    }
}
```

On the button it says 'View more'

Comment: [Don't use `on...` HTML attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Event_handlers#registering_event_handlers). Add that event listener on the JS side. Also, don't set `style` properties, make two (or more) CSS classes and then add/toggle/remove those as needed using the [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) accessor.  And finally, don't use `.innerHTML` unless you need to convert raw HTML source code to active page content. If you're just setting text, use `.textContent`.

Comment: And of course more directly related to your post: you're showing an input element that calls `search_filter`, but you're not showing that function, you're showing `view_all`... although related to those names: use JS naming conventions for variables, functions, etc. JS does not use snake_case like Python or C, it uses lowerCamelCase for variables, function, and class method.

Comment: Call `button.click()` to trigger a click on the button.

Comment: When should that button trigger exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener with the **"keypress"** property.

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event)
{
    yourFunction(event.key);
});
```

Something similar to this.
You can place a switch condition if you want a specific operation for a certain key.